# Solve for non-linear system of equations without computer

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find $a,b,c \in \mathbb R$ such that:
$$\left\{ 
\begin{align}
a+b+c &=4 \\
\left( a+b \right)  \left( b+c \right)  \left( c+a \right) &=18 \\
\frac 1 a+\frac 1b+\frac 1c &=\frac 52
\end{align}
\right.$$

---

How do I solve for $a,b$ and $c$ manually (without using a computer) ? Thanks !

All solutions are $(1,1,2)$ and permutations

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
a+b+c &=4 \\
\left( a+b \right)  \left( b+c \right)  \left( c+a \right) &=18 \\
\frac 1 a+\frac 1b+\frac 1c &=\frac 52
\end{align}
$$

It is useful to notice that all expressions here are expressible using [symmetric polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_polynomials) and, in turn, they are expressible using the elementary symmetric polynomials.
$S_1=a+b+c$, $S_2=ab+ac+bc$, $S_3=abc$

First equation is simply $S_1=4$.

From the second equation we get $(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)=2abc+a^2b+ab^2+a^2c+ac^2+b^2c+bc^2=(ab+ac+bc)(a+b+c)-abc=S_1S_2-S_3=18$.

The third one gives $\frac 1a+\frac 1b+\frac 1c =\frac 52$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $\frac{ab+ac+bc}{abc}=\frac{S_2}{S_3}=\frac52$.

So we have
$$\begin{align}
S_1&=4\\
S_1S_2-S_3&=18\\
S_2&=\frac52S_3
\end{align}$$
which has the solution $S_1=4$, $S_2=5$, $S_3=2$.

Now using [Vieta's formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) we get that $a$, $b$, $c$ are solutions of the cubic equation
$$x^3-4x^2+5x-2=0.$$

Now we can apply [rational roots test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem), which reveals that $x=1$ is a solution and then we get $x^3-4x^2+5x-2=(x-1)(x^2-3x+2)=(x-1)^2(x-2)$.
(Or we could employ one of the methods used for solving [cubic equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation).)

We can check the solution or [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a%2Bb%2Bc%3D4%2C+%28a%2Bb%29%28a%2Bc%29%28b%2Bc%29%3D18%2C+1%2Fa%2B1%2Fb%2B1%2Fc%3D5%2F2) or simply verify that $a=b=1$, $c=2$ fulfill the original system. (Of course, the permutations are solutions of the original equations, too.)